# Apple Xcode 8 seed submission issue: Invalid Toolchain

Tags: ios, xcode, ios10

I received that email from Apple encouraging me to submit my new iOS builds with the Xcode seed version provided yesterday.
And even the download website says:

> Xcode 8 GM seed may be used to submit apps to the App Store.

Yet when I do so and try to submit the new version with Application Loader (submitting by Xcode gave error 22421) I receive message:

> Invalid Toolchain - New apps and app updates must be built with the
>   public (GM) versions of Xcode 6 or later, macOS, and iOS SDK. Don't
>   submit apps built with beta software including beta macOS builds.

After having received a similar warning while uploading it.
Anyone knows the meaning of this?

Comment: Can you check the build number of your Xcode version ?

Comment: Yes: Version 8.0 (8A218a) the one on the developer website

Comment: Did you change the command line tools to the new version? Either in the command line `sudo xcode-select --switch /path/to/XcodeGM` or in the Xcode settings under Toolchains (I think)

Comment: see this https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/61884

Comment: I know this issue. Yet this time it is a seed version not a beta one. The formers are specifically provided for submitting apps before the new system comes out

Comment: Did you upgrade to macOS Sierra GM? I submitted an app with xocde 8 GM while on last sierra beta and got this message. After I upgraded macOS and re-submitted I did not get the message.

Comment: That might the issue. As a matter of fact my computer did not tease me to upgrade to the latest Sierra build and even now there is no such an option on the App Store. I long the days when you could upgrade your mac by downloading some code like you do with Xcode and the rest, instead of waiting for the App Store to make up its mind...

Comment: Even after updating to the seed version even for macOS the submission by Xcode keeps on giving error 22421. I am now tying with Application Loader.

Answer (score 0):

I had just faced this error and to me it work after these steps:

- in itunesconnect page, revoke and recreate developer certificates;

Edit provisioning profile to link the provisioning profile with the new certificate

-update Xcode to latest release

In xcode -> preferences -> accounts, delete related account and add it again

Then proceed with product - archive - validate/submit to appstore

Answer (score 0):

It is highly possible that you have the Xcode GM but you still use the Beta of OS X?